# How To Stop all Functions in JavaScript using an IF Function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use one function and a lot of IF functions to run this code.
I'm going to make this as a note app.
I want to add an IF function that has an class called stop-note.
I want to add it in the notes list for it's IF function then I want to add it to the "renderNotes" for it's link like style.

```
notesList.on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(e.target);
  var abort = false;

  // Listen to the selected note.
  if (target.hasClass('listen-note')) {
    if (abort) {
      return;
    }
    var content = target.closest('.note').find('.content').text();
    readOutLoud(content);
  }

  //Edit Note
  if (target.hasClass('edit-note')) {
    editText(content);
    var dateTime = target.siblings('.date').text();
    deleteNote(dateTime);
    target.closest('.note').remove();
    var content = target.closest('.note').find('.content').text();
  }


  // Delete note.
  if (target.hasClass('delete-note')) {
    var dateTime = target.siblings('.date').text();
    deleteNote(dateTime);
    target.closest('.note').remove();
  }
});
```

This is my function that runs my function above.

```
function renderNotes(notes) {
  var html = '';
  if (notes.length) {
    notes.forEach(function (note) {
      html += `<li class="note">
            <p class="header">
            <span class="date">${note.date}</span>
            <a href="#" class="listen-note" title="Listen to Note">Listen</a>
            <a href="#" class="edit-note" title="Edit Note">Edit</a>
            html = <button class="stop-note" onclick="abort = true">Stop</button>
            <a href="#" class="delete-note" title="Delete">Delete</a>
            </p>
            <p class="content">${note.content}</p>
            </li>`;
    });
  } else {
    html = '<li><p class="content">You don\'t have any notes yet.</p></li>';
  }
  notesList.html(html);
}
```

Comment: Please edit and highlight what you need help with. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abort` is a local variable, and you set it to `false` whenever they click on a note list. So `onclick="abort = true"` has no effect on the variable that's being tested in the function.

You need to make it a global variable.

```
window.abort = false;

notesList.on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(e.target);

  // Listen to the selected note.
  if (target.hasClass('listen-note')) {
    if (abort) {
      return;
    }
    var content = target.closest('.note').find('.content').text();
    readOutLoud(content);
  }

  //Edit Note
  if (target.hasClass('edit-note')) {
    editText(content);
    var dateTime = target.siblings('.date').text();
    deleteNote(dateTime);
    target.closest('.note').remove();
    var content = target.closest('.note').find('.content').text();
  }


  // Delete note.
  if (target.hasClass('delete-note')) {
    var dateTime = target.siblings('.date').text();
    deleteNote(dateTime);
    target.closest('.note').remove();
  }
});
```